# ORA-12505 :TNS listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, listener, tns

I am using Oracle database. I've written a small JDBC connection program in Java but I am facing an issue with the listener.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class JdbcConnection {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException,ClassNotFoundException {
        String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl";
        String user = "system";
        String password = "password";
        Connection connection = null;

        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
        if(connection!=null){
            System.out.println("Success in connnection");
        } else {
            System.out.println("failure in connection ");
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting the following exception:

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop>java JdbcConnection
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connectio
n with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor
The Connection descriptor used by the client was:
localhost:1521:orcl

        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java
:112)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java
:261)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:387)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:
441)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:165)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtensio
n.java:35)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:801)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        at JdbcConnection.main(JdbcConnection.java:18)
```

This is the output of `lsnrctl status`

```
LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 12.1.0.1.0 - Production on 16-JUN-2015 13:43
:41

Copyright (c) 1991, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Welcome to LSNRCTL, type "help" for information.

LSNRCTL> status
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for 64-bit Windows: Version 12.1.0.1.0 - Produ
ction
Start Date                16-JUN-2015 12:02:52
Uptime                    0 days 1 hr. 40 min. 52 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   C:\app\orauser\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\l
istener.ora
Listener Log File         C:\app\orauser\diag\tnslsnr\hydwemvm\listener\alert\lo
g.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1521ipc)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=hydwemvm)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

Comment: Could you show us the code?

Comment: Did you start the Windows services for Oracle and the listener on your computer?

Comment: Yes, services are running and I've restarting the services also.

Comment: Could you please add the output of `lsnrctl status` to your question?

Comment: Can you connect using `sqlplus system/password@orcl`?  Btw: you should ***never*** use the `system` account for application stuff. Create a regular user and use that. The `system` and `sys` accounts should **only** be used to administer the database. Never, ever create your own objects with those users.

Comment: Since the listener doesn't show the `orcl` service, the database doesn't appear to be up; or is up and was unable to register. Trying to connect locally through SQL\*Plus (without the `@orcl`) will show you which; or see which processes are running. An initial thought is that the listener is using `hydwemvm`, the DB may be trying to register using `localhost` or a fixed (stale) IP if you're using DHCP. Not enough information to tell though. Start by seeing what is actually running.

Answer (score 21):

If you know your oracle database SID, then use

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl
```

otherwise use below in case you have service name

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/orcl
```

Also, make sure service name with the name `ORCL` should be up and running. If still doesn't work, then you need to restart your machine and try again above.

**Still, not working ?** Then, try following :

Login with `SYSTEM` user and register **[`LOCAL_LISTENER`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/initparams109.htm#REFRN10082)** by running below SQLs.

```
alter system set local_listener = '(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))' scope = both;
alter system register;
```

---

**How to check oracle SID and service name :**

```
SELECT sys_context('USERENV', 'SID') FROM DUAL; -- It will return your oracle database SID

SELECT sys_context('USERENV', 'SERVICE_NAME') FROM DUAL; -- It will return your oracle database service name
```

Comment: I've tried with both the above formats still its no luck

Comment: Then, as I mentioned, restart your machine and try.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know the default SID of your database use this query in sqlplus:

```
SELECT sys_context('USERENV', 'SID') FROM DUAL;
```

Use this value in the JDBC URL instead of "orcl".

Answer (score 1):

Can you use the below URL?
Note the difference, this is to use the SERVICENAME instead of a SID.

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/orclservice
```

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same problem.

Try removing the LAN cable or disconnect your net connectivity and
restart the services of Listener and run the code.

It worked for me.